# Docker mounting image error executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a directory in which code files and subdirectories are, i want to mount these files to the docker image and run the index.py

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Selected base python version
FROM python:3.9.6

COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install all packages - see readme to create the requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Port the container listens
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3", "index.py"]
```

My build process is like this:

```
docker build -t demo .

docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 demo -v "$(pwd)":/.
```

However, the following errors occurs:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

What is wrong?

I tried different paths, but they all lead to the same errors.
Google the error didn't lead to any solution.

Comment: The run command Is currently commented out (but I want to run it later). But the error still persists.

Comment: And what command docker should run without command?

Comment: Also move all parameters (I mean `-v ...`) in front of image name (`demo`)

Comment: I'd suggest you don't want that `docker run -v` option at all; do make sure you `COPY` your code into the image, though, and declare a default `CMD`.  If you want to work on host code directly then a non-Docker Python virtual environment will be much easier.

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to the be able to not rebuild the container everytime I make a code change

Comment: @rzlvmp that solves the error. But it still doesn't find the index.py. I removed the comment in the docker file

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the file:

```
# Selected base python version
FROM python:3.9.6

COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install all packages - see readme to create the requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Port the container listens
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3", "app/index.py"]
```

and run:

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 -v "$(pwd)"/:/app demo
```